# How could "None" be equal to 0 in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, type-conversion

I find that in one table the `value "None" is equal to 0`

```
mysql> select distinct id from sometable where id="None";
+-------+
|  id   |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
```

Note that the type of id is `int(7)`!

Although all the value is shown as 0 in mysql client, when I use PyMySQL to query records in django, some of them are 0 while others are unicode "None", how could this happen?

Comment: You should read up on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: @P.Salmon Thank you very much!

Comment: If it helps, in the Python DB API, SQL NULL values are represented by the Python None singleton on input and output.

Comment: Now everything is clear. “None”=0 in MySQL is a matter of MySQL type-conversion, while the unicode value "None" appear in my python-based query is a representation of NULL value in a specified DB API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MySQL` loose with type conversions. When implicitly converting a string to a number, it will take characters from the start of the string as long as they are digits, and ignore the others.

In your example, `"None"` isn't digits, so `MySQL` will return `0`.

From Mysql [type-conversion](http://%20https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html)

> For comparisons of a string column with a number, MySQL cannot use an index on the column to look up the value quickly.

Implicitly converting a string  is horrible for performance, since you lose the usage on the index you may have on your column

---

Here is a sample to compare `"2arse"` string and `2` number, we can see when `ID = "2arse"` will return `ID = 2` row data because it will take digits `2` and ignore `arse` string to implicitly converting.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE sometable(
  ID INT
);
INSERT INTO sometable VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO sometable VALUES (2);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select distinct id
from sometable
where ID = "2arse";

| id  |
| --- |
| 2   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ExQBWGdo9kQBFPK4yTB7d/0)

Answer (score 0):

use cast to int then compare

```
select distinct id from sometable where cast(id AS SIGNED)=0
```

Comment: Dear friend, I want to know how did the administrator set "None"=0 because it is already there. For example， when I input `select "None"=0;`,the result is 1.